# Lubuntu 20.04 freezes

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu

I have recently installed Lubuntu 20.04 on a MacBook Air (2011).
From the beginning it froze practically every time I start it about half of the time it freezes even while trying to do the Login.

---

After implementing @heynnema's answer...

swapon -s

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file            4194300 3328    -2
```

---

free -h # confirm 2G RAM and 4G swap

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          1,8Gi       926Mi       174Mi       139Mi       731Mi       548Mi
Swap:         4,0Gi        15Mi       4,0Gi
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Sorry I missed your updates. You didn't notify me with a comment that started with @heynnema. Funny enough, `free -h` shows a 2G swap, but the `grep` doesn't show any swap lines in /etc/fstab. Curious. Show me `swapon -s` and `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Are you up to date on your MacBook Air BIOS/firmware updates?

Comment: @heynnema: $ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size          Used       Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition       2006012   141056    -2

Comment: Please add the output of my two commands as an edit to your original question, not in the comments, please. Also show me `cat /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks a lot for your help! Sorry, but I don't know what "BIOS/firmware updates" are - I'm always installing the updates for the OS (I have only Lubuntu installed).

Comment: You'll have to go to the MacBook Air support/downloads web page and look for the BIOS/firmware updates there. Apple doesn't call it BIOS... but I can't remember what their naming is. Add the four commands output to your question please.

Comment: Why not use Apple's Mac OS X instead of Lubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema, Sorry, but I can't see the four commands. The Mac OS X versions, which still get support do not work on this hardware, as the latter is too weak to deal with the extensive data requirement of the current Mac OS x's.

Comment: What "four commands" are you asking about? Also, see my minor edits to my answer to help you with the editing.

Comment: @heynnema, You wrote: "... Add the four commands output to your question please." I don't understand what you mean. The same goes for: ".., see my minor edits to my answer to help you with the editing." I don't see what you edited. I'm really sorry for all this trouble!

Comment: Do you need a `swappiness` value so high??  I realize you have very little RAM (I avoid using a thinkpad I have with only 2GB of ram) but with it that high it'll constantly want to swap memory in/out  (system will pause with disk light solid-on, or flashing very fast depending on your firmware)

Comment: @guiverc , thank you for your input. To answer your question: I don't know. If you think a lower value might be more likely to solve the problem, how much would you suggest?

Comment: I would normally boot a *live* system (eg. Lubuntu install media) on a system with 2GB of RAM (I have a thinkpad sl510 with that) & do some testing. I don't have time currently to do it, but I doubt a value of 80 would be best (default=60, higher value means it swaps RAM out to disk more often.. ie. encouraging *thrashing* is my concern, where *thrashing* will be a problem with that little RAM if you use a web browser). That however relates to operation, and should not impact login (I tested login on 19.04 with laptops with only 1GB of RAM without issue; 20.04 with 2GB).

Comment: Login can *feel* slow (and I'd disable *snaps* on 2GB if you're not going to need them; this will speed up login), but a slow login is not a freeze (a freeze I take it as being many minutes long), and a slow login shouldn't impact operation. Your results are inconsistent though; you mention swappiness as **60** (system default) once & **80** once (what grabbed me as excessive!) so maybe what I noticed was just a typo.

Comment: @guiverc , Login is not unusually slow, but the freezes are pretty much permanent - until I shut it down and start again.

Comment: I tried to work with swappiness 60, but it did not improve the issue. With the previous LTS version it never froze.

Comment: Previous I take it as 18.04 LTS, were you using the GA or HWE kernel?  Did you re-install or upgrade (problems on upgrade were to be expected it said in the release notes due to desktop change).  I'd boot install media (20.04 & 20.04.2 media) & try using that to see if you get your 'freezing'... If you were using the GA (4.15) kernel it maybe an issue with a 5.4/5.8 kernel module (ie. driver); which kernel are you using? (20.04 with GA = 5.4, 20.04 with HWE is 5.8 currently)

Comment: @guiverc , I don't know which kernel the 18.04 LTS OS was working with, nor which I am using now. I did a re-install for 20.04. How can I find out which kernel I'm using?

Comment: `uname -r` will provide details of the currently running kernel. A 20.04 system will report 5.4 for a GA kernel being used and 5.8 for a system on the HWE kernel  (note: that's current; HWE upgrades during the life of the system and will *bump* next to 5.10 but that hasn't occurred yet)

Comment: @guiverc , uname -r
5.4.0-66-generic

Comment: @guiverc Regarding your prior comment about vm.swappiness... please note my answer... I had OP increase /swapfile, and increase vm.swappiness, to, as you say, with only 2G RAM... increase swapping, intentionally. OP hasn't been able to complete my answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big problem is that you only have 2G RAM. Best to add more RAM if possible.

In the mean time, let's modify your current swap setup. We change from using a 2G swap partition, to a 4G /swapfile. And we modify vm.swappiness to increase swapping.

**/swapfile**

First we create a 4G /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile
```

Note: or `sudo swapoff /dev/sda3` and skip the `sudo rm`...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 2G RAM and 4G swap
```

Now edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Add this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab (use spaces, not tabs)...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

Then save the file and...

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**2G swap partition**

`sudo swapon -s` may still show /dev/sda3 as your swap.

`sudo swapoff /dev/sda3` # disable disk partition swap

Use `gparted` to delete /dev/sda3.

`reboot`

**vm.swappiness**

Then we increase swapping...

Now edit /etc/sysctl.conf, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` or `sudo pico /etc/sysctl.conf`.

Add `vm.swappiness=80` to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot.

**Finally...**

Confirm that this is all working with these commands...

`free -h` or `swapon -s`

and confirm 4G /swapfile.

And...

`sysctl vm.swappiness` should show 80.

Comment: I don't understand how to: "Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab" and how to: "Add vm.swappiness=80 to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot."

Comment: @manoka 1) Use one of the two edit commands that I gave as an example. Then add the /swapfile line. 2) Use similar command(s) to edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add the highlighted string at the end of that file.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't understand how to do everything after "Finally...".

Comment: @manoka You did something wrong, as the swap looks broken now. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /swapfile` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Add this output to the END of your question and I'll take a look what went wrong.

Comment: @manoka You forgot to edit /etc/fstab and add `/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0`. Please re-read my answer for details. Report back. Also, when updating your question with new data, make sure to send me a comment that starts with "@heynnema", without the quotes, or I'll miss your updates.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know exactly how "to edit /etc/fstab and add /swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0". Do you mean to execute the command like this: "sudo pico /etc/fstab/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0", or should I execute the command "sudo pico /etc/fstab" first, and then add "/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0" somewhere to the output?

Comment: @manoka The latter. Use either edit command to open the file. `gedit` is probably easier for you. Then add "/swapfile none swap sw 0 0" to the end of the file. Then reboot. Then do `free -h` and confirm a 4G swap.

Comment: When I execute the command "sudo pico /etc/sysctl.conf" I get this output (see at the end of my question) - and I seem to be unable to add anything there.

Comment: @manoka That's why I suggested that you use the `gedit` command instead of the `pico` command... it'll be easier for you.

Comment: I added "/swapfile none swap sw 0 0" to the end of the gedit file. I pasted the output of "free -h" at the end of my question. But I don't know how to "confirm a 4G swap".

Comment: @manoka Show me `tail /etc/fstab` and `tail /etc/sysctl.conf` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Then reboot. Do `free -h` and the output should indicate 2G RAM and 4G swap.

Comment: I did what you recommended and added the requested outputs to the end of my question.

Comment: @manoka I don't see the new outputs in your question.

Comment: @manoka Oh, there they are... we've discussed this before... don't edit my answer... edit new outputs into your original question.

Comment: @manoka The edits don't show up in /etc/fstab, so your /swapfile is still not working at all. The edits to /etc/sysctl.conf look fine.

Comment: what can I do that /etc/fstab will work.

Comment: @manoka Just follow the detailed instructions that I left for you. Edit the file with `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`, add the /swapfile line that I show, save the edits, reboot. Very simple.

Comment: I did everything from your instructions from "vm.swappiness" to the end. The outputs I pasted to the end of my question. Unfortunately when rebooting it freezed for the first time even before the login page appeared.

Comment: @manoka The errors that you received when doing `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` are just noise, due to a different bug, but it shouldn't stop you from editing /etc/fstab and adding the `/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0` line at the end, saving the edit, then rebooting.

Comment: @manoka Status please...

Comment: it still freezes (sometimes preceeded by dropouts), although not so often during login, but more often after some time of surfing.

Comment: @manoka Let's verify where you're at right now. Edit your question and show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `grep -i vm.swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf` and `free -h`.

Comment: I added the requested outputs to the end of my question. I just noticed that the issue has something to do with having two different browsers open at the same time. When I'm using only one, the system works a lot faster and with less freezing. I also removed a brave browser, which I installed according to commands of an unofficial website - as I could not find the software catalog after I installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. I will let you know how it works within 24 hours.

Comment: @manoka Your /etc/fstab now looks fine. Your vm.swappiness looks fine. But your swap still isn't working. Show me `swapon -s`... it should say `/swapfile`. You may have to recreate the 4G /swapfile following my instructions.

Comment: @manoka Have you rebooted since fixing /etc/fstab? If not, reboot, and that might get your /swapfile to work.

Comment: I added the requested outputs below my question.

Comment: @manoka Hurrah! It's finally working. Good job! The reboot fixed it. If my answer helped to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: thank you so much for all your patience and efforts! The system is now working without issues. Though I wonder whether this was a shortcoming of the new Lubuntu version, or whether it is just an issue due to a particular hardware. I wish I could do something for you in return - if I could, please don't hesitate to let me know!

Comment: @manoka Glad it's all working as it should :-)